# A way of bruteforcing a hash value without the use of file

Tags: hash

First of all, this question is about this thread I made lately ;
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32370/a-way-of-bruteforcing-a-hash-value-without-the-use-of-file

> An example is better than explanation.
>
> Let's say we have this md5 hash : `15e0adc0213e01ec44acee74ed4ece5b`
>
> All I know is this hashing method is md5, the length of the clear text is of 6 and the charset is [a-zA-Z].
>
> Now, I have to find the clear text just with these informations.
>
> **What I originally would do**
>   
>   I would simply, using the 'crunch' software on linux, create a file with all the possibilities.
>   Then I would write a script that calculates the hash of each line and search the whole file until I find the one I'm looking for.
>   Unfortunately, since [a-zA-Z]{6} generates a 131GB file, this method is not recommended. I need to find another way.
>   
>   **An alternative I'm thinking of**
>   
>   I was thinking of and searching for a way to bruteforce this hash, the same way as I described above, but without using a file. 
>   Is there a script (whatever the language) that is similar to this 'code' ;
>
> ```
> for(int i=0; i<[a-zA-Z]{6}.size(); i++){
>     int result = md5_function(i)
>     if( result == '15e0adc0213e01ec44acee74ed4ece5b' ) {
>         cout << "Result : " << result << endl;
>     }
>     else {}
> }
> ```
>
> How can I implement this code?

Now what I wanted to know, is how do I implement this idea ?

Comment: I don't know about the other downvotes, but mine was because you didn't even bother to copy-past. ​ ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive implementation in C# would look similar to this:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(char[] charset, int length)
{
    if(length == 0)
    {
        yield return "";
        yield break;
    }
    foreach(var s in GetCombinations(charset, length-1))
    {
        foreach(var c in charset)
        {
            yield return s + c;
        }
    }
}
```

The trick here is that an [iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) doesn't need a collection or file backing it. It can lazily produce the next element once `MoveNext` gets called.

```
foreach(var s in GetCombinations("abc [...] zABC[...]Z", 6))
{
    if(hash(s)==targetHash)
        yay(s);
}
```

---

Much uglier and less flexible but also much easier to understand:

```
foreach(var c1 in charset)
{
    foreach(var c2 in charset)
    {
        ...
            foreach(var c6 in charset)
            {
                var s = c1 + c2 + ... + c6;
                if(hash(s)==targetHash)
                    yay(s);
            }
        ...
    }
}
```